# How to dimensions in mm of barcodes/qrcodes generated with pst-barcode for sticky labels - i.e. when using `labels` package?

Tags: pst-barcode, barcodes, sticky-labels, business-cards

How to specify dimensions of barcode in mm ? (when using `pst-barcode` and `labels` packages)

`scalex`,`scaley` seems to work. Why not absolute dimensions specifications ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} % require -shell-escape
\LabelCols=4%
\LabelRows=11%
\LeftPageMargin=7mm%
\RightPageMargin=7mm%
\TopPageMargin=15mm%
\BottomPageMargin=2mm%
\InterLabelColumn=0mm%
\InterLabelRow=0mm%
% These four parameters give the extra space used around the text on
% each actual label.
\LeftLabelBorder=4mm%
\RightLabelBorder=4mm%
\TopLabelBorder=4mm%
\BottomLabelBorder=4mm%
\begin{document}

% Specification of 4mm x 4mm seems not respected
\numberoflabels=4
\boxedaddresslabel{
\begin{pspicture}(4,4mm)
\psbarcode{38}{includetext guardwhitespace}{ean2}
%\psbarcode[scalex=0.2,scaley=0.2]{38}{includetext guardwhitespace}{ean2}
\end{pspicture}
}

% Specification of 0.1in x 0.1in seems not respected
\numberoflabels=4
\boxedaddresslabel{
\begin{pspicture}(0.1,0.1in)
\psbarcode{38}{includetext guardwhitespace}{ean2}
%\psbarcode[scalex=0.2,scaley=0.2]{38}{includetext guardwhitespace}{ean2}
\end{pspicture}
}

% but scalex, scaley seems respected
\numberoflabels=36
\boxedaddresslabel{
\begin{pspicture}
\psbarcode[scalex=0.1,scaley=0.1]{38}{includetext guardwhitespace}{ean2}
\end{pspicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Command line

```
pdflatex -shell-escape input.tex
```

[image]

Notes:

If `mm` are not possible or overcomplicate code, let it be in `in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\begin{pspicture}(0.1,0.1in)` makes no sense. Without a unit or a preceding `\psset{unit=1in}` it is always cm. Same for  `\begin{pspicture}(4,4mm)`. You have to specify both units if not the default one:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} % require -shell-escape
\LabelCols=4%
\LabelRows=11%
\LeftPageMargin=7mm%
\RightPageMargin=7mm%
\TopPageMargin=15mm%
\BottomPageMargin=2mm%
\InterLabelColumn=0mm%
\InterLabelRow=0mm%
% These four parameters give the extra space used around the text on
% each actual label.
\LeftLabelBorder=4mm%
\RightLabelBorder=4mm%
\TopLabelBorder=4mm%
\BottomLabelBorder=4mm%
\begin{document}
    \numberoflabels=4
    \boxedaddresslabel{%
        \begin{pspicture}(4mm,4mm)
        \psbarcode{38}{height=0.158 includetext guardwhitespace}{ean2}
        \end{pspicture}%
    }

    \numberoflabels=4
    \boxedaddresslabel{%
        \begin{pspicture}(0.1in,0.1in)
        \psbarcode{38}{width=0.1 height=0.1 includetext guardwhitespace}{ean2}
        \end{pspicture}%
    }

\end{document}
```

`height=` and  `width=` are used on PostScript level and are *always* in the unit inch. `4mm=4/25.3 in=0.158in`

[image]

`scalex` and `scaley` are used on TeX level.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it works! Btw. `(1,1in)` kind of artifacts come from dumb copy&pasting of [pst-barcode-doc.pdf](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pst-barcode/pst-barcode-doc.pdf) manual.